# javascript method executing twice - bootstrap-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider

I have n dynamically generated sliders each with the given DOM id `slider{n}`.
Because I don't know how many sliders I will have, I have attached my `on slideStop` event to the class, and then using `$(this)` to get the id, and do whatever's relevant to that slider.

```
$(".slider").on("slideStop", function(slideEvt) {

    var rowoffset = $(this).attr("id").substring(6);
    $("#percentage" + rowoffset).text(slideEvt.value);
    updateNumbers(rowoffset);

});
```

Everything works as planned except the script is executing the `updateNumbers()` method twice.

As you can see here my `postdata` is logged to console twice along with each response, one with the correct values, and a 2nd call which has undefined values.

it's clear that the first response is a response to the 2nd call.

1. Why is my method firing twice? Is it something to do with the slider library or jquery?
2. How come the response to the failed call comes back first even though the failed call is always executed 2nd?

[image: console]

Here is the updateNumbers method, which certainly doesn't call its self.

```
function updateNumbers(rowoffset){

  //get variables from DOM element values

  var percentage = $("#slider" + rowoffset).val();
  var group = $("#rrgroup").val();
  var rrclass = $("#rrclass").val();
  var category = $("#rrcategory").val();
  var subcategory = $("#subcategory" + rowoffset).val();
  var period = $("#rrperiod").val();
  var year = $("#rryear").val();
  var yearmonth = $("#rryearmonth").val();
  var rangesize = $("#rangesize" + rowoffset).text();

  var storesstring = $("#rrstores").val();
  if(storesstring == ""){

     storesarray = [];

  } else {

  var storesarray = storesstring.split(",");

  }

  var postdata = {percentage: percentage,
                  group: group,
                  class: rrclass,
                  category: category,
                  subcategory: subcategory,
                  period: period,
                  year: year,
                  yearmonth: yearmonth,
                  stores: storesarray,
                  rangesize: rangesize};

                  console.log(postdata);

         $.ajax({
          url: "ajaxrangemix.php",
          type: "post",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: postdata,
          success: function (response) {

              console.log(response);

              $("#dropskus" + rowoffset).text(response.skus);
              $("#keepsales" + rowoffset).text(response.sales);

              },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

              console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }


      });

}
```

HTML

```
            <div class='panel-body' id='rangemixbody'>

                <input type='hidden' id='rrgroup' value="<?php echo $group; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' id='rrclass' value="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' id='rrcategory' value="<?php echo $category; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' id='rrperiod' value="<?php echo $period; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' id='rryear' value="<?php echo $yr; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' id='rryearmonth' value="<?php echo $yrmth; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' id='rrstores' value='<?php implode(",", $storename); ?>'>

                <table class='table table-striped'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Subcategory</th>
                            <th><span>0%</span><span class="pull-right">100%</span></th>
                            <th>%</th>
                            <th>Current Range Size</th>
                            <th>Drop Skus</th>
                            <th>Keep Sales</th>
                            <th>Sales Share</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    $subcategories = array();
                    foreach($rangereviewarray as $row){
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" id="subcategory<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row['subcategory']; ?>">
                                <?php $subcategories[$i] = $row['subcategory']; ?>
                                <?php echo $row['subcategory']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="slider<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" class="slider" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="100" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span id="percentage<?php echo $i; ?>">100</span>%
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span id="rangesize<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $row['rangesize']; ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="dropskus<?php echo $i; ?>">0</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" id="sales<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['sales']; ?>">
                                <span id="keepsales<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo number_format($row['sales'], 2); ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo number_format($row['share'], 2); ?></td>
                        </tr>

                    <?php
                    $i++;
                    }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
             <input type='hidden' id='rrsubcategories' value='<?php implode(",", $subcategories); ?>'>
            </div>
```

Comment: May you post your html too?

Comment: Maybe you reference the js file twice

Comment: Regarding question 2: the functions you set in the `success` and `error` properties are _callbacks_. These callbacks are _async_, meaning they can be executed in any order, at any time. It just depends on when the request is completed. In this case, the error gets back quicker than the success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to determine the reason for the event fire twice from the question. My only suggestion, based on the attached screenshot, is to cancel the request when the slider is not related to any DOM element:

```
function updateNumbers(rowoffset){

    var $el = $("#slider" + rowoffset);
    if( $el.length == 0 ) {
         return;
    }

    //get variables from DOM element values

    var percentage = $el.val();
    var group = $("#rrgroup").val();
    var rrclass = $("#rrclass").val();
    var category = $("#rrcategory").val();
    var subcategory = $("#subcategory" + rowoffset).val();
    ..... rest of the function
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great workaround. I've posted my html aswell, but I don't think this will bring any news regarding why it's happening. I can't help but think it's something to do with the slider library.